# Why is insertion order not preserved in MultiMap?

Tags: java, multimap

```
public class MultiMap_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

          myMultimap.put("classlabel", "tid");
          myMultimap.put("Y", "1");
          myMultimap.put("Y", "2");
          myMultimap.put("N", "4"); 

          // Iterating over entire MutliMap
          for(String value : myMultimap.values()) {           
              System.out.print(value);
          }
    }
}
```

The above code prints `1 2 tid 4`.

I am not understanding why it is not printing `tid 1 2 4`.

Comment: Maps don't keep the order of items.

Comment: This is the contract of `MultiMap`s... This is the price to pay for query-in performances.

Comment: One option is to use `Map<String, List<String>>` instead. That will give you the insert-in-order property.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `LinkedListMultimap` instead if you want to keep the insertion order:

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
```

Comment: Does LinkedListMultimap allows duplicate key ?

Comment: @vikramvi Yes LinkedListMultimap allows duplicates

Answer (score 3):

> Why is insertion order not preserved in MultiMap?

In fact, your problem is not with `MultiMap` but with the selected implementation. [`ArrayListMultimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.java) uses a `HashMap<K, Collection<V>>` as implementation of the backing `Map<K, Collection<V>>`:

```
public static <K, V> ArrayListMultimap<K, V> create() {
    return new ArrayListMultimap<K, V>();
}

//...

private ArrayListMultimap() {
    super(new HashMap<K, Collection<V>>());
    expectedValuesPerKey = DEFAULT_VALUES_PER_KEY;
}
```

And `HashMap` doesn't preserve the order of the insertion of the elements.